# Free memory from a pointer to pointer - C destructor

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

If I have the next function

```
Stack *construct_stack(void) {
  Stack *instance = (Stack *) malloc(sizeof(Stack));

  // Stuff...

  return instance;
}
```

It's sort of "constructor". But I'v been having problems with the "destructor".

If I do this I get an error.

```
void destruct_stack(Stack **st) {
  // Stuff...

  free(st);
}
```

Some idea?

Comment: Why you pass pointer to pointer ? just pass a pointer and free it .

Comment: `free(*st);*st=NULL;`

Comment: 'Cause my code looks like this:  
    `Stack *s = construct_stack();  
    // Stuff...  
    destruct_stack(&s);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void destruct_stack(Stack **st)
```

Here `st` is pointer to pointer(i.e `instance`) to which you allocate memory (`st` holds address of pointer `instance`).

```
 free(st); // you didn't allocate memory to st therefore gives error
```

So you should free `*st` like this

```
   free(*st);
   *st=NULL;  // just a good practice
```

Or another way instead of address of the pointer(i.e `&instance`) you can pass the pointer `instance` itself and then `free` it but you will need to change the type of parameter which is passed to function.

Answer (score 3):

```
void destruct_stack(Stack **st) {
  // Stuff...

  free(*st);//free the pointer which st points to
  *st = NULL;//set it to null
}
```

And You don't need to cast the result of malloc: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)